# Calling state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one function which gets a value and after setting state calls another function, however, after I try to log that state into the console in the second function (generatePdf), it doesn't log anything, as if the state wasn't updated. Does anyone know where is the problem?

```
pickMonth=(value)=>{
  this.setState({ m: value }, ()=>console.log(this.state.m), this.generatePdf())
}

generatePdf(){
  const {m} = this.state
 console.log(m);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pickMonth=(value)=>{
  this.setState({ m: value }, ()=> { console.log(this.state.m), this.generatePdf() })
}
```

after u set the state above, m is not immediately available because set state is async. you should pass m as an argument.

```
pickMonth=(value)=>{
  this.setState({ m: value }, ()=>console.log(this.state.m), this.generatePdf(value))
}

generatePdf(value){

 console.log(value);
}
```

Comment: that will not work, setState takes two arguments

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this, you don't need to use an arrow function inside your pickMonth function, you can directly do `console.log(this.state.m); this.generatePdf();` :

```
pickMonth = (value) => {
  this.setState({ m: value };
  console.log(this.state.m);
  this.generatePdf();
}

generatePdf(){
  const {m} = this.state
  console.log(m);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`generatePdf` will not called , you need to this

```
pickMonth=(value)=>{
  this.setState({ m: value }, ()=> {
        console.log(this.state.m);
        this.generatePdf();
   }
)}
```

`setState` takes two arguments the first is the state and the second is optional for the callback
you passed three args which is wrong

Answer (score 1):

The return value of `this.generatePdf()` is currently passed as the third argument of `this.setState(...)`. Since `setState()` only accepts two arguments, the third argument will be unused. `this.generatePdf()` is not part of the callback (second argument). If you where planning to use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) within the callback you'll have to wrap the body with parentheses.

```
this.setState({ m: value }, () => (console.log(this.state.m), this.generatePdf()));
```

Since `setState()` does not use the return value of the callback you might as well use body brackets `{ ... }` instead of using an expression. This is generally speaking easier to understand as well.

```
this.setState({ m: value }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.m);
  this.generatePdf();
});
```

The difference here is that the above callback returns `undefined` (since it has no return statement). While the former callback implicitly returns the expression result (the return value of `this.generatePdf()`).